# Is there an efficient way to pass a list of args to a QString, by avoiding copies?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

Lets say I have a list of N arguments which I want to pass to a QString. The number N is variable and determined at runtime.

If I do this:

```
QString myString = "Some text %1, some other text %2,..., some more text %n"
for(auto arg : list) {
  myString = myString.arg(arg);
}
```

I create a lot of string copies, as I can only change one .arg at a time, and need to save one copy of the string in each iteration. Is there a more efficient way? I looked into the documentation for something like QString::args(SomethingIteratable), but found nothing.

Comment: Do you know [QStringList](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringlist.html)? Also the arg() method can take [several parameters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#arg-14).

Comment: I know of QStringList, but don't see how it can help me with passing arguments. Yes, the .arg method can take several parameters, but not at runtime. So I can do .arg(1,2,3), but not .arg(vector) where vector is filled at runtime.

Comment: a [mcve] would probably help to understand the question better. In your example `""%1, %2,..."` has exactly 2 placeholders to be replaced. I suppose your actual use case is different

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? Is `list` extremely large or is the loop called very often? If it's a one-off thing when starting your program, the inefficiency of copying a few strings is probably negligible.

Comment: If 'efficiency' is your concern then you might want to consider using, say, `std::stringstream ss`, perform the various `ss << ...` operations and then finish with `auto myString = QString::fromStdString(ss.str())`?

Comment: Before question "edit": this should be fine: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstringlist.html#join after edit check: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstring.html#arg-14

Comment: `Is there a more efficient way?` Why do you care? Is this code in some time critical part? Are you doing some measurements to prove this part of code impacts your performance?

Comment: @G.M. Or in C++20 use std::format

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have worded my question porly. The problem is not that I need a string of the specific form "%1, %2, %3", but i have a string which contains some text (determined at runtime) with sone placeholders somwhere within text, which need to be replaced with arguments in an efficient manner.

Comment: @G.M. `std::stringstream` performance sucks and you have to do conversion to `QString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some hard-coded limit (to transform runtime vector size to compile time one), you might use `arg()` overload taking several `QString`

```
std::variant<
    std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 1>,
    std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 2>
    std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 3>
    std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 4>
    std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 5>
    // Adapt to your limit
    >
as_integral_constant(std::size_t n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 1: return std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 1>{};
        case 2: return std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 2>{};
        case 3: return std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 3>{};
        case 4: return std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 4>{};
        case 5: return std::integral_constant<std:size_t, 5>{};
        // adapt to your limit...
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Unsupported size");
}
```

And then, `visit`:

```
QString args(QString format, const std::vector<QString>& list)
{
    const auto size = as_integral_constant(list.size());
    return std::visit([&](auto N){
        return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
            return format.arg(list[Is]...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<N()>());
    }, size);
}
```

Notice than `arg` in one pass might behave differently than multipass, especially if your inserted texts contain `%1`.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple, just `reserve` some memory up front and do the simplest thing possible:

```
QString myString;
myString.reserve(1'000'000);
{
  QTextStream ts(&myString);
  for (auto arg: list) {
    ts << arg << ", ";
  }
}
myString.resize(myString.size() - 2);
myString.squeeze();
```